# Turning off and Flickering of LEDs for some reason

Tags: voltage, current, resistance, flipflop

I've been following Ben Eater's You Tube series on building an 8 bit computer. As I built and connected more modules to the same power source, the LEDs connected to the registers started to flicker and turn off. I added a few more batteries in parallel and it worked fine. After I added more modules (ALU, RAM), they began to flicker and turn off again. Wrong data was being represented by the LEDs. I have double checked the connections and there seems to be no error in it. Is this a battery problem? How can I go about solving this issue?
Below is a video describing the mentioned problem:
[Buggy circuit](https://youtu.be/W_0wON1Qnbc)

Comment: Use a DVM and measure the supply voltage.

Comment: @Free Radical He has a video on power supply issues, have you seen it?

Comment: @Tyler thank you, I've just watched it. I think there might be an issue with my breadboard as it is of low quality.

Comment: A nice game :-). | It appears that you have about zero bypass / power supply capacitors. | There are many ways that may work, but eg: Every breadboard has a substantial electrolytic cap (or equivalent) where the power feed connects. Ideally every IC has a bypass capacitor from ground to Vcc (if two rails) with as short a physical and electrical path from the IC connection points. These are traditionally 100 nF ceramics but not too crucial at slow speeds. Additional electrolytics added at higher demand points "won't hurt".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a power problem. If you are using [TTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor%E2%80%93transistor_logic) chips, be aware that they are more power hungry than the equivalent [CMOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMOS) chips.

It is not necessarily a battery problem. [Breadboards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadboard) are not known for being the best at power delivery, and there are certainly quality differences between breadboards. You're going to have power losses - [voltage drops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_drop) - in each and every connection. If you use thin and/or long jumper wires for [GND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_(electricity)) and [VCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IC_power-supply_pin), there may also be a significant voltage drop in the wires themselves.

(You may also want to consider the placement and [ESR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalent_series_resistance) of your [bypass capacitors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decoupling_capacitor).)

As Andy aka suggests, check your supply voltages. Measure directly between GND and VCC at each chip while the circuit is running.

If the wires or connections are not up to the task, adding more batteries in parallel will only go so far.

Comment: There are zero bypass capacitors visible in the video!

Comment: I used a bypass capacitor for the clock with the 555 timer. I guess it's not clearly visible in the video.

Answer (score 1):

A nice game :-).

It appears that you have about zero bypass / power supply capacitors.
They are essential.

There are many ways that capacitors can be distributed but eg

- Every breadboard has a substantial electrolytic cap (or equivalent) where the power feed connects.
- Ideally every IC has a bypass capacitor from ground to Vcc (if two rails) with as short a physical and electrical path from the IC connection points. These are traditionally 100 nF ceramics but not too crucial at slow speeds.
- Additional electrolytics added at higher demand points "won't hurt".
- Measure power supply voltage at each breadboard. This should be within device requirements at all locations. If there are differences in VCC across the system this may affect marginal situations.
- If available use an oscilloscope to observe power supply noise at each breadboard at the points furthest electrically from the supply feed connections.